# Wing Chun - Fighting Stance

Tags: kung-fu

What is the standard hand form for fighting stance, Man Sao or Tan Sao?

For me, Tan Sao should be more appropriate as more flexible to dodge, absorb energy and attack as Wing Chun is a softness technique. Or just a relax mode to preserve energy.

Donnie likes position his hand like man sao or more like a karate style for me. His left hand not with wu sao or defense position or seem meaningless?

[image]

Ip Man often show as tan sao.

[image]

[image]

Post Note:
As some of the comments below, this Tan Sao seems seems as a defense and waiting hand for a strike from opponent, absorb energy and return with a blow or grabbing or whatever.
Reference
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWDkBePpE0Q

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145875/discussion-on-question-by-banana-tech-wing-chun-fighting-stance); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: As noted, this has generated a lot of commenting back and forth. Comments are intended to refine questions and answers. Please continue the discussion in the created chat room.